# Default Audio device not changing to new hardware

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, audio, windows-registry

When I plug in a new audio device (IE. Connect to a bluetooth speaker, plug in an HDMI cable, plug in a USB speaker) the default communication device changes to that device as expected,  **however the default audio device does not automatically change to the newly plugged in speaker**. I suspect that the issue is a registry value as the default communication device still automatically changes fine and that would have broken if it was a driver issue (right?).

Answer (score 0):

This should not be an issue. My HP 600G1, my lenovo laptop, and hp laptop all keep the default audio device to the onboard speakers/audio, but when plugging in a headphone, the sounds plays out of the headphone only as expected.

Are you experiencing an issue with the actual sound playback? IE. the sounds not coming out of the newly connected device? Or do you just want the sound control panel to display the new device and make it default?

Comment: It is an issue as it used to work fine, it broke a while ago. Please don't just tell me there is no problem, there obviously is.

Comment: is sounds coming out of the devices? your question has some vague areas, as i said, my default device does not change, but it still plays the audio exclusively out of the attached device. 

If it broke a while ago why don't you retrace your steps back to what happened the day it broke, your not doing yourself any favors by supply little to no back info on the issue. We don't even know what OS you are using, the model/brand or even the audio driver.

Good luck guy